# How to inject keystrokes via a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, keyboard, input

I'm trying to inject keystrokes into the input daemon so as to simulate typing from a Bash script. Is this possible, and if so, how can I make it happen?

Comment: Do you want to simulate input at the kernel level (if so, on what OS), at the X level, in a terminal?

Comment: At the kernel level, I'd like it to essentially appear as if I hit an actual key on an actual keyboard.

Comment: @TKKocheran: So, under AIX? FreeBSD? Linux? OSX? … The answer is highly likely to be completely different on each variant.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, I'm operating under Linux, Ubuntu 11.04 64bit.

Comment: What do you need that for?

Comment: Perhaps I'd like to write a script that randomly inserts keypresses at random intervals.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are operating at the X level (as in Gilles' question), then use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) like so:

```
xdotool key KEYSTROKE_SPECIFIER
```

Where KEYSTROKE_SPECIFIER can be something like "a" or "F2" or "control+j"

EDIT: I missed your response to Gilles' question, sorry. I'll leave this response here as a solution for the X-case.

Comment: I think `xte` operates at the same level.

Answer (score 24):

Use the `uinput` driver. I don't think there's a utility for that; you're going to have to write or adapt a bit of C code. In a nutshell:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/uinput.h>
/* Set up a fake keyboard device */
fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK); // or /dev/input/uinput
ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
struct uinput_user_dev uidev = …;
write(fd, &uidev, sizeof(uidev));
ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE);
/* Send an event */
struct input_event ev = …;
write(fd, &ev, sizeof(ev));
/* Clean up */
ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_DESTROY);
close(fd);
```

More complete references:

- [Using uinput driver in Linux-2.6.x to send user input, by Mehul Patel](https://web.archive.org/web/20120710121647/http://www.einfochips.com/download/dash_jan_tip.pdf)
- [Gettig started with uinput, by Gregory Thiemonge](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput)

Comment: The link to einfochips.com was broken. I replaced it with a snapshot from archive.org.

Comment: do you think this could help on solving this question? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156985/keyboard-hard-remap-keys, I thought, when I press a key, this program would send another key that the problematic application actually recognizes (even if at the same time)?

Comment: Thiemonge's sample code for creating and moving around a mouse works, can't figure out how to make keystrokes from it though even if it supposedly teaches that.

Comment: @Cestarian This sounds like a question for [so]. Post your code, explain what you expected and what you see instead, and provide any relevant error messages, log entries etc.

Comment: @Gilles well I'd love to, but it says i've reached my question limit... For getting too many downvotes on 2 questions I asked a while back; and probably some more on much older questions I deleted. Hell, I don't even know why I got so many downvotes here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619023/refreshing-a-list-of-variables-with-one-command (got a pretty good answer though), was it because I didn't post the error I was receiving maybe? Anyhow, off topic. Basically I would but can't. :(

Answer (score 12):

If you're NOT working with X programs with windows that can be sent keys, you are probably looking for [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), a handy and very configurable program for running other interactive shell programs as if a user were controlling the terminal. You can setup programatic responses to respond to various output with different inputs.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote some Python code that does that. You can find it in my open source project.

http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/core/pycopia/OS/Linux/event.py

If you run that module as a script as root you can see a demo in action.

This basic functionality was extended for another project, powerdroid, that provides more concrete implementation for an embedded system (Android).

http://code.google.com/p/powerdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/droid/devices.py