# How to create a fake device file that accepts input from a C program?

Tags: linux, c

I want to create a C program that accepts input from a joypad (`/dev/input/js0`), processes it, and then sends it to a fake device file (character *or* block) labeled as a keyboard (oh, and what *is* the device file for a keyboard?.  I would like to know if it is possible to do this, and if so, how.

Comment: I think this covers the central part of your question: [How to inject keystrokes via a shell script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14879)

Comment: Do you actually want to send data to the keyboard or do you want data to look like it came from a keyboard? For the later there already is a kernel driver called uinput. I have never used it as a programmer, but you can start here http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput

Comment: @user1129682: What do you mean by sending data *to* the keyboard?  Do you mean injecting keystrokes on a TTY level?  And as for what I want to do, I would like to know how to send characters on as low a level as possible, but X.org (GUI) stuff will do fine.  Oh, and I believe that you mean 'latter', not 'later'.

Comment: With data to the keyboard I mean data/bits being sent from your kernel to the actual device with the many keys and some leds. :-) So you are trying to get data to X. In that case uinput is exactly what you are looking for. Look for the toolchain to connect a wiimote to X. They use uinput to send keystrokes to X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at an excerpt from an `ls -al /dev` command on my system:

```
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,   0 Jun  7 19:55 sda
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,   1 Jun  7 19:55 sda1
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,   2 Jun  7 19:55 sda2
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,   3 Jun  7 19:55 sda3
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,   5 Jun  7 19:56 sda5
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,   6 Jun  7 19:56 sda6
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,   7 Jun  7 19:56 sda7
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,   8 Jun  7 19:57 sda8
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,  16 Jun  7 19:55 sdb
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,  32 Jun  7 19:55 sdc
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,  33 Jun  7 19:55 sdc1
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,  34 Jun 11 10:39 sdc2
brw-rw----  1 root floppy    8,  35 Jun  7 19:56 sdc3
```

The two numbers after the group ID but before the date are the device file's major and minor numbers.  This is basically the "kind" of device it is.  8 in this case is a SCSI (or emulated SCSI) disk drive.

http://lxr.linux.no/linux/Documentation/devices.txt is a somewhat not-so-recent list of all the major and minor numbers.  Not sure of the official location of the latest version of the list.

So anyway, these files are created with the `mknod` command (`mknod [OPTION]... NAME TYPE [MAJOR MINOR]`, some types are `b` for block, `c` for character).  There's also a `mknod()` system call.  I don't fully know the implications if you create another file with the same major/minor as an existing device.

`uinput` as described in the comments is probably what you are looking for, although on PC hardware there is a `/dev/psaux` that reads/writes directly to the PS/2 port if your system is old enough to have one.  Could not even tell you where to begin with USB keyboards ...

If you just want a fake device file and don't care what happens to the data you send to it, there's always `/dev/zero`.  Also symlinks may be a real simple solution in that case.