# Can I control a graphical program from the command line?

Tags: scripting, x11

How can I enter text in the text fields of the window shown by a program in an automated manner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to inject keystrokes via a shell script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/how-to-inject-keystrokes-via-a-shell-script)

Comment: @muru, I don't agree it's a duplicate. Here it's more specific and can call for different answers: typically one or the other of the existing X application testing frameworks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah. I was looking for an existing post for `xdotool`, and thought that one was general enough.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the linux terminal"_? What do you mean by _graphical program_? A X11 one?

Answer (score 1):

In order to simulate user input you can use `xdottool` which is mentioned in comments to your question.

Besides, there is [xaut](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xautomation/) (formerly xautomation) python lib. You cas simulate mouse movement and mouse clicks, keystrokes, and manipulate windows from Python.

Moreover, there's [X11:GUITest](http://search.cpan.org/~ctrondlp/X11-GUITest-0.28/GUITest.pm) perl package. This can be used to interact (SendKeys, ClickMouseButton, FindWindowLike, etc.) with applications running under an X Windows environment. Including applications built (GTK+, Qt, Motif, etc.) upon X11 / Xlib.