# Unable to simulate Ctrl+Shift+Fn+F10 Key press \

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, laptop

I have an `ubuntustudio 16.10` 64 bit on an IBM Thinkpad E431. I am able to launch an app from a shell script, but the next step involves pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> On my notebook I need to press the button <kbd>Fn</kbd> before <kbd>F10</kbd> . I use `xfce` Desktop. I am unable to simulate this in a shell script.  I had also disabled my touchpad but did not help.

Comment: It's worth making a related point. Fn keys can do weird things under the hood. For example, if I do Fn+F8, I get a volume-up keypress event coming from my keyboard, but if I press Fn+12 (labelled airplane mode), an event appears to come into Linux from my network card. Looking at what events are coming into which /dev/input/* files can help work out what's going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## You do not need to.

> On my notebook I need to press the button <kbd>Fn</kbd> before <kbd>F10</kbd>.

That is, however, irrelevant to what X input events you need to simulate.

What you have to remember is that the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is never seen on the wire between your keyboard and your computer.  It is handled entirely by the microprocessor in the keyboard itself.  What comes over the wire when you press the keys with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> engravings is simply the key code for the <kbd>F10</kbd> key, as if you had a full keyboard with a fully-fledged independent <kbd>F10</kbd> key.

You have a key that is engraved with <kbd>F10</kbd> and something else.  The keyboard microprocessor handles your <kbd>Fn</kbd> key as an *entirely local modifier key* that switches that key between looking like the "something else" key (when <kbd>Fn</kbd> is not pressed) on the wire and looking like the <kbd>F10</kbd> (when <kbd>Fn</kbd> is pressed) on the wire.

In fact, laptop and suchlike keyboards usually have two such local modifiers.  The other is the state of the NumLock LED (sic), making every key have four different ways in which it can appear on the wire to your computer.

But as seen by your computer, at the other end of the wire, all of this is invisible.  It sees a full keyboard with a real, independent <kbd>F10</kbd> key.  That is also what the X applications see in X input events.

So that is all that you need to simulate.  Just simulate X events that indicate that the <kbd>F10</kbd> key has been pressed, with the <kbd>Level2 ⇧</kbd> and <kbd>Control ⎈</kbd> modifiers.

With `xdotool`, as in flowtron's answer, that's just

```
xdotool key ctrl+shift+F10
```

## Further reading

- [Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't recognize Fn key](https://askubuntu.com/a/787771/43344)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2020). *[The "Fn" key is local.](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/fn-key-is-local.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- "[KEYBOARD MATRIX DESIGN](http://sprintek.com/documents/datasheets/DS0026_SK5126_Datasheet.pdf#page=7)". *SK5126 FlexMatrix Keyboard Controller data sheet*.  Sprintek.  2015-02-20.
- "[Function Key Usage](http://farnell.com/datasheets/79209.pdf#page=18)". *HT82K629A Windows 2000 USB+PS/2 Keyboard Encoder data sheet*.  Holtek.  2004-09-15.

Comment: nicely done - why didn't I take the time to elaborate? upvote!

Answer (score 4):

use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) as mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14883/77959).

```
xdotool key KEYSTROKE_SPECIFIER
```

Where KEYSTROKE_SPECIFIER can be something like "a" or "F2" or "control+j"

Answer (score 1):

The simulated key with `xdotool` may not be captured on a bash/shell if `xdotool` is not run in a forked way instead of `xdotool key ctrl+shift+F10` you can use

```
xdotool key ctrl+shift+F10 &
```

If the keys are captured by your shell/terminal application, it will be occupied by xdotool when it's ran to simulate the keys preventing it from capturing them because the main process is busy simulating the keys... forking the process with `&` will make the main process free to capture the keys.