# Keyboard issue console terminal

Tags: debian, kernel, keyboard

I have an issue on my Debian computer with Intel Stick.

Link to screenshot => [image: https://ibb.co/HDHcYr5]

I have extra character in console tty like ^[

This issue is only with supperior 4.11.12 kernel

Debian kernel and 4.11.12 kernel is ok

I dont know why

Comment: The way to restore the tty settings to normal is to run the command reset, which is done by ^Jreset^J (the ^J is ctrl-J, press the ctrl and J keys simultaneously). ^] is the telnet(1) escape character

Comment: Hi Boschko, thanks for answer, i have try to do CTRL + J simultaneously and...no solve my issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not your TTY settings, and the `reset` command (which you could not even execute anyway, as you have not logged in) will gain you nothing.  Indeed, in most modern Linux operating systems the terminal *has just been* reset before running the `login` program (by dint of systemd's `TTYReset=yes` setting or otherwise), and that has clearly had no effect.

This is your <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> key being stuck down, or the kernel's built-in terminal emulator thinking that it is.

When the kernel's built-in terminal emulator sees <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> plus an alphanumeric key, it transmits the character sequence `␛` (U+001B) followed by the character for the key to the input of the line discipline.  And `^[` is how the line discipline echoes back an `␛` character when it receives one as input (and it is in canonical mode, as it is here).

So `^[r` is how <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> is echoed back to you.

It's possible for the terminal emulator's idea of what modifier keys are currently pressed to become out of synch with the actual keyboard state, for reasons beyond the scope of this answer.  Press and release all of your <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> keys, *without* pressing any of the key chords that switch amongst the kernel VTs, and the state should become synchronized again.

If that does not work, then the next thing to investigate is whether the modifier key is indeed physically stuck down.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391968/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428865/5132

Comment: Hi JdeBP, your answers is very good. I managed to unlock by holding down the CTRL and ALT key and tapping all the keys on the keyboard ... it looks like the kernel thinks that the ALT key is pressed.
What would be the best solution to try to solve this problem of ALT blocked? while he is not.

I have this problem only with kernels greater than 4.11.12