# Cant login to the Debian machine

Tags: linux, debian

I use a `Debian 8 OS` in the `MacBook Pro` with the Parallel Desktop.

At the time I was editing the `.bashrc` file as root, things get messed up. I can't close the complete black window whatever I try (e.g `contr+ z`, `contr+ x`, `:wq`, `:x` etc). I'm somehow moved to the BELOW position at the lines of instructions in the image provided`(close, save etc)` but I can surely type.

[image]

I shut down the VM and when I come back again, this is exactly the same. I have some work that needs to be done.

What should I do at this point?

UPDATE

[image]

Will it end the current session if I remove as shown?

Comment: Did you try to open a second session on the server? In that session you can find the process of the editor and kill it.

Comment: The VM must be recovering from a saved state which is why it comes back. You could switch to another TTY with Ctrl+Alt+F1-F12. It's possible the current TTYs PTS is frozen somehow.

Comment: @jdwolf Whats the TTY? I'm new to Linux and VM both

Comment: @Marco How to open another session? The VM starts from the saved state everytime I try

Comment: @Marco There is an option for the remove though as in the image. Should I try that?

Comment: @jdwolf There is an option for the remove though as in the image. Should I try tht?

Comment: @Arefe No don't do that. Resume the VM. Press Ctrl+Alt+F2 once its started.

Comment: This doesn't help as I log in to the same nono full black screen. Other commands mentioned in the question also doesn't seem to work for me. What is the remove do actually? Will it delete the Debian installation instance with all the data? That will be a lose surely.

Comment: To those voting to close this question as unclear: This question is _Help! I cannot exit `nano`!_.

Comment: The issue is solved as I get an option to stop the VM later on in the same window than the remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the same nono full black screen

The program is named `nano`.  It is a text editor.  The command to exit it is the 1980s-style <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> key chord, that is displayed right there in the 1980s-style menu lines at the bottom of the text editor screen.

> the complete black window

This is a *virtual terminal* a.k.a. *virtual TTY* being presented by your *guest* operating system running in the virtual machine.  (Yes, it is a virtual thing within a virtual thing.)

You can switch amongst several virtual terminals with the key chords <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, which might be hotkeys for your *host* operating system or translated by the Parallels Desktop's keyboard translation layer, and which thus you might have to simulate with other key chords in order to send to the guest operating system in the virtual machine.

Of course, the fact that `nano`'s screen is visible on the virtual terminal does not mean that `nano` is running.  Kill the `nano` process with the `KILL` signal, for example, which is what you might have done, and one is left with the `nano` menu lines on screen and the shell prompt somewhere in the middle, mixed up with whatever text one was editing at the time.

In such a situation <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will indeed not appear to do anything.  You will have *already terminated* `nano`, and the shell input prompt that you are now at does not do anything visible in response to those characters. (<kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> is the beginning of a multiple-character editing control sequence in emacs mode in ZLE and Bourne Again shell readline.)

Another possibility, hinted at by your claim that <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> did nothing, and on the assumption that you do know how to send this to the guest operating system through your host operating system's hotkeys and Parallels Desktop's keyboard translation layer, is that the virtual keyboard has a virtual modifier key stuck as depressed.

This is militated against, though, by three things.

- `nano` displays a status message next to the menu lines in response to things like <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (although things like <kbd>⇮ AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> can be ignored silently, depending from your chosen keyboard layout);
- you may already be using virtual terminal #2, in which case switching to it will indeed be a no-op;

  and
- if the stuck modifier were <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> or <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>, pressing those should have un-stuck it for the guest operating system.

> The issue is solved as I get an option to stop the VM later on in the same window than the remove.

After all of the things that people say about exiting `emacs`, exiting `vim`, and exiting `vi`, it is very amusing to see the "solution" to exiting `nano` presented as being *to restart the entire (virtual) machine*.  ☺

## Further reading

- [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2012). *[Exiting `emacs`](http://jdebp.eu./Humour/exiting-emacs.html)*.  Humour.
- *[ALT, CTRL and SHIFT keys are not working while using RDP client in Windows virtual machine](http://kb.parallels.com/en/123130)*.  2015-07-15.  KnowledgeBase #123130.  Parallels.
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85978/
- *[Change the behavior of function keys on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204436)*.  2017-12-13. HT204436.  Apple corporation.
- [Unable to simulate Ctrl+Shift+Fn+F10 Key press \](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331395/)

Comment: This is very informative and I read it briefly as I'm at work now. I will again read the whole after I back in the home. Thank you so much.