# Function (FN) key has no output in xev

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard

So neither of my function keys appear to be working on my Asus laptop running Arch Linux. They're definitely not broken but they don't produce any output in xev. Like it doesn't register a keypress or anything.

Any ideas on what's wrong? And if so how can I fix this?

Comment: Are these the keys that make some other double-labelled keys behave as F1-Fn, PgUp, Home, etc, or something else? It's unlikely that they generate any signals of their own if so.

Comment: That's probably by design, and there's nothing Linux, X11, or you can do about it. But try FN-Left;  it may produce some key (`XK_AudioLowerVolume` ?)

Comment: Yeah I did some more testing; using the FN key in conjunction with other keys does produce output. So probably an electrical/hardware thing.

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331395/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467099/ , and https://askubuntu.com/questions/787707/ .

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that this is intended behavior, seeing as combinations of keys (Fn-F1, Fn-F2, etc.) do produce output in xev.