# How to get the keybind on a keyboard's special FN key? Showkey and xev can't find it

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, i3

I'm trying to map the special 'FN' key on a Logitech K360 keyboard to 'Mod3' in the i3wm window manager on Debian. However, I can't find the keycode for the 'FN' key. Showkey and xev don't return any value when 'FN' is pressed. However, the FN key does work and returns different single values in line with the FN default settings. For example, xev and showkey shows 'End' when I press the End key, but returns 'Pause' when I press FN+End.

Solaar doesn't seem to have any settings that help with this.

How do I get the keybind for 'FN'? Thanks.

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/493351/5132 again.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is handled by the keyboard, not by the operating system, which is not even aware of the existence of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. As far as the OS is concerned, <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> are two unrelated keys with different scancodes. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key does not produce a scancode by itself and cannot be independently detected by the OS.