# keyboard freezes sometimes with Fn key

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, keyboard

Sometimes, using Linux Mint Mate 19, my keyboard freezes completely. The mouse still moves.

This happens sometimes when I am using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to e.g. change the volume (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>). I cannot exactly reproduce it, but it happens weekly. I guess it happens when using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys too quick, and at the same time I use the mouse to select something, or I type another key while <kbd>Fn</kbd> is still being hold or processed.

After it freezes, one solution is to restart the computer.

Other solution that sometimes work is to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> volume up/down and then use the mouse and select or touch randomly other keys. At some point it starts working again.

Any idea why this is happening? Is there a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key combination that disables the keyboard that I am unaware of? Or is it a bug?

The laptop keyboard is this one: laptopkeyboard.com/keyboards/clevo/w-series-clevo/w650-backlit

Comment: People aren't going to be of much help if you do at least not tell them the type of keyboard (manufacturer and model) and connection that it is using (USB or PS/2).  That key is not handled by your operating system.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467190/5132

Comment: It is this laptop keyboard: https://www.laptopkeyboard.com/keyboards/clevo/w-series-clevo/w650-backlit/